# Karaf - How to check whether the application is running?

Tags: osgi-bundle, karaf

I have an application build using OSGI 
with a maven build converted the application into jar
The jar i've installed by placing it in deploy folder of karaf

When I use list command it shows me that the application is Active ,
Its a service application 
When I try to access it from a project outside it shows that service is not active..

Kindly help me know How to check and make applications in karaf to run ?

Comment: Are you trying to access the service from another bundle inside Karaf or from another process external to Karaf? Do you have the Karaf web-console loaded in your features? It can be very helpful when looking at the 'state' of individual bundles.

Answer (score 0):

From the karaf commandline, type:

```
system:property | grep webconsole
```

to see if the webconsole is running and if so, what port it is running on.  Then, in your browser navigate to:

```
<ip of machine running karaf>:<webconsole port>/cxf
```

That will show you your active services.